# Getting the redirect URL using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I would like to get the redirect URL using `cURL` in PHP.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
public function request($uri = null)
{
    $redirects = 0;

    if ($uri === null) {
        $uri = $this->getUri();
    }

    while ($redirects < $this->options['maxredirects']) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->options['useragent']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->options['timeout']);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        $this->addResult($result, $info);

        if (floor($info['http_code'] / 100) != 3) {
            return null;
        }

        $redirects++;
    }
}
```

I don't what to use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, because (correct me if wrong) that automatically follows the redirect.

I was hoping it would have been in `curl_getinfo()`, but it isn't. It looks like I have to enable `CURLOPT_HEADER` and parse the header to get the 'next' URL.

- Is this correct?
- If "Yes" how would I be able to parse the header? E.g. can I safely `explode()` the string on `\n` and find the item which starts with `Location:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true` and then parse the string by exploding it with `\r\n`.
There is also other ways, but not sure if they are valid in your case - [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php

Comment: And how would I distinct between the `headers` and the `body` in the response?

Comment: The headers and body are separated by `\r\n\r\n`. You could also set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` if you don't want the body.

Comment: And are they `\n` or `\r\n` delimited. Or is this IIS vs Apache?

Comment: Always `\r\n\r\n`, this is HTTP.